# sending large JSON data from server - should I compress?

Tags: php, javascript, json, http

I am sending large datasets in JSON format from my server (using PHP). I want to keep bandwidth costs down. I am wondering:

1. should I gzip compress the JSON data server side before sending the data?
2. is there a javascript gzip uncompression library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should compress your output (but only for transmission). But you can let your sever do it for you. If you use a standard compression on HTTP level the client will decompress that automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should <s>gzip</s> compress it — but at the web server level, not the application level. Then neither your server- nor client-side code needs to worry about it, it happens as part of the HTTP transfer. In Apache, for instance, you configure this via [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html). In nginx, you use the [`Gzip`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule) module. Any half-decent web server will allow you to compress content on-the-fly (including dynamic content).

Answer (score 0):

If you send this data to a grid you could reduce the sent data by paging the grid. This way only a certain number of rows is sent to the grid and the rest of the data will be sent on request.